# Converting a custom 2D sparse matrix into a network

Tags: r, graph, type-conversion, sparse-matrix

I have such an array exported from a program and looks like :

```
1 2:1.827411e-02 3:5.355330e-02 4:1.827411e-02 5:1.827411e-02
2 1:1.827411e-02 3:1.903553e-02 4:4.568528e-03 5:4.568528e-03
3 1:5.355330e-02 2:1.903553e-02 4:1.903553e-02 5:1.903553e-02 6:7.461929e-02 11:3.350254e-02
4 1:1.827411e-02 2:4.568528e-03 3:1.903553e-02 5:4.568528e-03
5 1:1.827411e-02 2:4.568528e-03 3:1.903553e-02 4:4.568528e-03
6 3:7.461929e-02 7:1.903553e-02 8:1.903553e-02 9:5.355330e-02 10:1.903553e-02 11:3.350254e-02
7 6:1.903553e-02 8:4.568528e-03 9:1.827411e-02 10:4.568528e-03
8 6:1.903553e-02 7:4.568528e-03 9:1.827411e-02 10:4.568528e-03
9 6:5.355330e-02 7:1.827411e-02 8:1.827411e-02 10:1.827411e-02
10 6:1.903553e-02 7:4.568528e-03 8:4.568528e-03 9:1.827411e-02
11 3:3.350254e-02 6:3.350254e-02
```

Each line describes the edges' weight (after the colon symbol) between the first number of the line and the number before the colon symbol.

i.e for the first line:

```
the weight between 1 and 2 is 1.827411e-02
the weight between 1 and 3 is 5.355330e-02
the weight between 1 and 4 is 1.827411e-02
the weight between 1 and 5 is 1.827411e-02
```

So on and forth for the rest of lines.

This info I would like to convert it somehow into an igraph or network element to do more analysis on it. Is there any efficient way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can a little regex to pull out the relevant values to form a weighted edge list.

```
# parent node : grab the first number
parent <- sub("(\\d+ ).*$", "\\1", r) 

# child node: grab everything after the first number and split it
child <- strsplit(sub("\\d+ (.*$)", "\\1", r), ":| ")

# cbind the parent node to the child    
dat2 <- cbind(rep(parent, lengths(child)/2), matrix(unlist(child), nc=2, byrow=TRUE))

mode(dat2) = "numeric" # change to numeric


# read in a graph: the weights are in the edge attributes
g <- igraph::graph_from_data_frame(dat2)
```

---

**Data**

Assuming your data is of this form in a text file (change `textConnection(txt)` to the path to your file)

```
txt <- 
  '1 2:1.827411e-02 3:5.355330e-02 4:1.827411e-02 5:1.827411e-02
2 1:1.827411e-02 3:1.903553e-02 4:4.568528e-03 5:4.568528e-03
3 1:5.355330e-02 2:1.903553e-02 4:1.903553e-02 5:1.903553e-02 6:7.461929e-02 11:3.350254e-02
4 1:1.827411e-02 2:4.568528e-03 3:1.903553e-02 5:4.568528e-03
5 1:1.827411e-02 2:4.568528e-03 3:1.903553e-02 4:4.568528e-03
6 3:7.461929e-02 7:1.903553e-02 8:1.903553e-02 9:5.355330e-02 10:1.903553e-02 11:3.350254e-02
7 6:1.903553e-02 8:4.568528e-03 9:1.827411e-02 10:4.568528e-03
8 6:1.903553e-02 7:4.568528e-03 9:1.827411e-02 10:4.568528e-03
9 6:5.355330e-02 7:1.827411e-02 8:1.827411e-02 10:1.827411e-02
10 6:1.903553e-02 7:4.568528e-03 8:4.568528e-03 9:1.827411e-02
11 3:3.350254e-02 6:3.350254e-02'

r <- readLines(textConnection(txt))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Do you know how can I take into account the weights in plotting? I used `plot.igraph( g, edge.width=E(g)$weight)` and didn't seem to change the width of edges.

Comment: as the weights are similar you probably won't see much difference. You could rescale ie `E(g)$weight2 <- X* E(g)$weight / max(E(g)$weight)` , and multiply by some constant `X` (say, `X=10`) that allows a difference to be seen